# How to append string to tableview from separate ViewController using alert

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to append string using an alert in createPlaylistVC to a tableView in another ViewController createdPlaylistVC.

I've looked up this answer and it didn't do much for me
[add a row to the tableView from another viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987470/add-a-row-to-the-tableview-from-another-viewcontroller)

**CreatePlaylistVC**

```
var crdPlaylistVC = CreatedPlaylistVC() 

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:.default, handler: {
action in

    if let playlistName = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
    self.crdPlaylistVC.emptyArray.append("Your playlist: \(playlistName)")

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.crdPlaylistVC.emptyArray.count - 1, section: 0)

    self.crdPlaylistVC.tableView?.beginUpdates()
    self.crdPlaylistVC.tableView?.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    self.crdPlaylistVC.tableView?.endUpdates()
    self.crdPlaylistVC.tableView?.reloadData()



    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let SEC: CreatedPlaylistVC  = segue.destination as! CreatedPlaylistVC
        SEC.emptyArray.append("Your playlist: \(playlistName)")
        self.crdPlaylistVC.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

**CreatedPlaylistVC**

```
class CreatedPlaylistVC:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var emptyArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playlistCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = emptyArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return emptyArray.count
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code cannot work. `createdPlaylistVC()` is never the instance in the storyboard.

You have to call `performSegue` in the action and pass the string as `sender`. And `prepare for` must be on the top level of the class

```
var crdPlaylistVC = createdPlaylistVC()
```

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:.default) { [weak self] action in
    if let playlistName = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
       self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyIdentifier" sender: playlistName)
    }
}


func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "MyIdentifier" else { return }
    let playlistName = sender as! String
    let sec = segue.destination as! createdPlaylistVC
    sec.emptyArray.append("Your playlist: \(playlistName)")
}
```

You have to reload the table view in `createdPlaylistVC` because the table view might be not connected yet.

And please conform to the naming convention that class names start with an uppercase letter and variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Hey you're code works but my only problem is I don't want to perform a segue to the CreatedPlaylistVC when it's done. I want to go back to another VC which is the main VC right now.

Comment: You didn't mention this crucial point in the question. Please edit the question and add the code how you go from the main controller to the create controller.